# Invalid property specified for object of type plotly.graph_objs.sankey.Link: 'customdata'

Tags: python-3.x, plotly

I am trying to add custom data to my links and nodes on Sankey Chart. I am referring to plotly's official [website](https://plotly.com/python/sankey-diagram/) .

Using the code available on their website:

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go
fig = go.Figure(data=[go.Sankey(
    node = dict(
      pad = 15,
      thickness = 20,
      line = dict(color = "black", width = 0.5),
      label = ["A1", "A2", "B1", "B2", "C1", "C2"],
      customdata = ["Long name A1", "Long name A2", "Long name B1", "Long name B2",
                    "Long name C1", "Long name C2"],
      hovertemplate='Node %{customdata} has total value %{value}<extra></extra>',
      color = "blue"
    ),
    link = dict(
      source = [0, 1, 0, 2, 3, 3], # indices correspond to labels, eg A1, A2, A2, B1, ...
      target = [2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 5],
      value = [8, 4, 2, 8, 4, 2],
      customdata = ["q","r","s","t","u","v"],
      hovertemplate='Link from node %{source.customdata}<br />'+
        'to node%{target.customdata}<br />has value %{value}'+
        '<br />and data %{customdata}<extra></extra>',
  ))])

fig.update_layout(title_text="Basic Sankey Diagram", font_size=10)
fig.show()
```

I am getting an error, as per their documentation we can use `customdata` to display additional data.  I am not sure if the documentation on their website isn't upto date or if I am doing something wrong. Appreciate your help in advance.

> Invalid property specified for object of type plotly.graph_objs.sankey.Link: 'customdata'

Comment: I ran the code and cannot reproduce your error. What version of Plotly are you using?

Comment: Ahh the issue was resolved I was using Plotly 4.6. Reinstalled Plotly 4.14.3 and it works fine now.

Comment: Awesome! I've [posted my comment as an answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/294791/what-if-i-answer-a-question-in-a-comment) so people with the same question as you can see that there is a solution. Feel free to upvote/accept the answer if it was helpful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `customdata` property is valid for a Plotly Sankey Chart graph_object as of the most recent version of Plotly (v4.14.3 at the time of posting this answer), and a description for this property can be found in the [latest documentation](https://plotly.github.io/plotly.py-docs/generated/plotly.graph_objects.Sankey.html). Updating plotly to the latest version should resolve the issue.